# Integrating tests written in Python and tests in C# in one solid solution

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, unit-testing

What I'm trying to do is to combine two approaches, two frameworks into one solid scope, process ...

1. I have a bunch of tests in `python` with self-written `TestRunner` over `proboscis` library which gave me a good way to write my own Test Result implementation (in which I'm using `jinja`). This framework is now a solid thing. These tests are for tesing UI (using `Selenium`) on **ASP.NET** site.
2. On another hand I have to write tests for business logic. Apparently it would be right to use `NUnit` or `TestDriven.NET` for `C#`.

Could you please give me a tip, hint, advice of how I should integrate these two approaches in one final solution? May be the answer would be just to set up a CI server, donno...

Please note, the reason I'm using Python for ASP.Net portal is in its flexibility and opportunity to build any custom Test Runner, Test Loader, Test Discovery and so on...

P.S. Using `IronPython` is not an option for me.

P.P.S. For the sake of clarity: `proboscis` is the python library which allows to set **test order** and **dependency of a choosen test**. And these two options are the requirements!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you feel you *need* "a custom test runner, test loader, test discovery and so on"? Is there any concrete reason you're not just using NUnit with WebDriver/Selenium for the UI testing?

Comment: Hi, Jon. Nice to see your comments :). Well, the customer requested a few interesting features: customizable test reports (html, markdown, whatever.) via jinja2 template engine; adding GitHub issue status to generated reports; uploading markdown report to another github repository. So, Python fully fits.

Comment: None of that sounds like it requires a different test *runner*. Just use NUnit to run the tests, and then you can write whatever code you want to format the results from the XML that NUnit generates.

Comment: I didn't mention two features: ability to **test reorder** and ability to set **dependency for tests** which do require a custom test runner.

Comment: I suspect you could build that within NUnit pretty easily. But at this point given the extra highly-specific requirements coming out, I suspect this question is really too localized...

Comment: Yes, I know, it's a bad practice. But for what kind of projects? Any kind? I highly doubt... Sometimes the things should be changed. In my case this is required - the system is huge and run every test from the initial state is unaffordable and even pointless.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. May be NUnit is just what I need. I will take a close look at it...

Comment: Sorry, but these requirements indeed **were mentioned** in my question, Jon. You just missed that. `proboscis` is exactly for test reordering and setting test dependency.

Comment: No, you said that you were using probscis. You didn't say why. Stating a proposed *solution* isn't the same as stating *requirements*.

Comment: You can specify particular tests for NUnit to run, so I expect you should be able to get it to do what you want. `nunit-console.exe /?` is quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can fit them in one runner or process. I'm also not that familiar with Python. It seems to me that the Python written tests are more on a high level though. Acceptance tests or integration tests or whatever you want to call them. And the NUnit ones are unit test level. Therefore I would suggest that you first run the unit tests and if they pass the Python ones. You should be able to integrate that in a build script. And as you already suggested, if you can run that on a CI server, that would be my preferred approach in your situation.